# What is an elegant way to animate a Makie.jl plot recipe for Agents.jl in Julia?

Tags: plot, julia

Let's say we've got the following Agents.jl + Makie.jl workflow:

```
using Agents, Random, AgentsPlots, Makie, Observables


mutable struct BallAgent <: AbstractAgent
    id::Int
    pos::Tuple{Float64, Float64}
    vel::Tuple{Float64, Float64}
    mass::Float64
end

function ball_model(; speed = 0.002)
    space2d = ContinuousSpace(2; periodic = true, extend = (1, 1))
    model = AgentBasedModel(BallAgent, space2d, properties = Dict(:dt => 1e0, :i => Observable(0)))

    Random.seed!(1001)

    for ind ∈ 1:500
        pos = Tuple(rand(Float64, 2))
        vel = (sincos(rand(Float64) * 2π) |> reverse) .* speed
        add_agent!(pos, model, vel, 1e0)
    end
    index!(model)

    return model
end

agent_step!(agent::BallAgent, model) = move_agent!(agent, model, model.dt)

function AbstractPlotting.:plot!(scene::AbstractPlotting.Plot(AgentBasedModel))
    ab_model = scene[1][]
    position = Observable([a.pos for a ∈ allagents(ab_model)])

    on(ab_model.i) do i
        position[] = [a.pos for a ∈ allagents(ab_model)]
    end

    scatter!(scene, position, markersize = 0.01)
end


function create_animation()
    model = ball_model()

    scene = plot(model)
    display(AbstractPlotting.PlotDisplay(), scene)
    for i ∈ 1:600
        Agents.step!(model, agent_step!, 1)
        model.i[] = i
        sleep(1/60)
    end
end
```

Now since AgentsPlot.jl doesn't support Makie, I have to make a recipe for it and currently the way I update the plot is by registering a callback that updates the positions observable, which gets passed to scatter.

The thing is I am registering that callback on an Int observable, which is attached to the AgentBasedModel, that is created specifically for this. It just seems like an ugly way to go about this.

`model = AgentBasedModel(BallAgent, space2d, properties = Dict(:dt => 1e0, :i => Observable(0)))` i is the observable which we attach the callback to like this:

```
  on(ab_model.i) do i
        position[] = [a.pos for a ∈ allagents(ab_model)]
    end
```

and I have to update it here so the callback gets called like so:

```
  for i ∈ 1:600
        model.i[] = i
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to make it more elegant is to add a callback on the model itself and then use `Observables.notify!(model)` to fire the callback(s). This way you wouldn't need another variable to keep track of but I still feel like it can be made more elegant.

```
using Agents, Random, AgentsPlots, Makie, Observables


mutable struct BallAgent <: AbstractAgent
    id::Int
    pos::Tuple{Float64, Float64}
    vel::Tuple{Float64, Float64}
    mass::Float64
end

function ball_model(; speed = 0.002)
    space2d = ContinuousSpace(2; periodic = true, extend = (1, 1))
    model = AgentBasedModel(BallAgent, space2d, properties = Dict(:dt => 1e0))

    Random.seed!(1001)

    for ind ∈ 1:500
        pos = Tuple(rand(Float64, 2))
        vel = (sincos(rand(Float64) * 2π) |> reverse) .* speed
        add_agent!(pos, model, vel, 1e0)
    end
    index!(model)

    return model
end

agent_step!(agent::BallAgent, model) = move_agent!(agent, model, model.dt)

function AbstractPlotting.:plot!(scene::AbstractPlotting.Plot(AgentBasedModel))
    model = scene[1]
    position = Observable([a.pos for a ∈ allagents(model[])])

    on(model) do _model
        position[] = [a.pos for a ∈ allagents(_model)]
    end

    scatter!(scene, position, markersize = 0.01)
end


function create_animation()
    model = Observable(ball_model())

    scene = plot(model)
    display(AbstractPlotting.PlotDisplay(), scene)
    for i ∈ 1:600
        Agents.step!(model[], agent_step!, 1)
        Observables.notify!(model)

        sleep(1/60)
    end
end
```

Edit: `Observables.notify!(model)` simply does `model[] = model[]`